# Why cant I import java.time.ZonedDateTime into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, time

I have Java 8 installed and worked in my Eclipse project as far as I can tell. This line does not work though:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
```

I also can't seem to get:

```
import java.time;
```

to work either.

It tells me this line cannot be resolved. I thought this was part of standard Java 8 library? Is there a place I am meant to go to download the JAR for the ZonedDateTime class or something?

I'm making AWS Lambda functions in eclipse, if that matters.

I went into the properties for the project and noted the compiler compliance level was set to 1.6, so I changed this to 1.8. now I get a warning that says:

When selecting 1.8 compliance, make sure to have a compatible JRE installed and activated (currently 1.6).

When I go to the link it provides for installed JREs i only see 1.6. How do I get and install the 1.8 JRE so that it will appear from this list as selectable?

Comment: what do you have as JRE System library in the eclipse project?

Comment: Where do I find what I have for the JRE System library in the project?

Comment: Just confirmed it seems the JRE is 1.6 for this project.

Comment: there you are... you need java8

Answer (score 0):

All those Classes are only available since java 8,
make sure your project have in the **JRE System library** in the eclipse project the right  version

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window > Prefrences > Java > Installed JREs
Select your JDK 8 directory.

Also go to project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> select JRE System Library click Edit and select JDK or JRE after then click Java Compiler

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your Eclipse IDE if JAVA is of correct version(1.8 or above).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).